# Gradle: share repository configuration between settings.gradle.kts and buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There is a Gradle 6.X multi-module project using Kotlin DSL.
`buildSrc` feature is used to manage dependency versions in a central place. Something similar to the approach described [here](https://proandroiddev.com/gradle-dependency-management-with-kotlin-94eed4df9a28).

The project uses an internal server to download dependencies.
It causes the duplication of the repository settings configuration in two places:

**`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`**:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    // The org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm plugin requires a repository
    // where to download the Kotlin compiler dependencies from.
    maven {
        url = uri("${extra.properties["custom.url"] as? String}")
        credentials() {
            username = extra.properties["custom.username"] as? String
            password = extra.properties["custom.password"] as? String
        }
    }
}
```

and root **`settings.gradle.kts`**:

```
...
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("${extra.properties["custom.url"] as? String}")
                credentials() {
                    username = extra.properties["custom.username"] as? String
                    password = extra.properties["custom.password"] as? String
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Is it possible somehow to share the duplicated `maven` block between these two places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try refactoring your `kts` file into something like this. Does this help you?

`repositories.gradle.kts`:

```
repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("${extra.properties["custom.url"] as? String}")
                credentials() {
                    username = extra.properties["custom.username"] as? String
                    password = extra.properties["custom.password"] as? String
                }
            }
        }
```

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
apply(from="../repositories.gradle.kts")
```

`settings.gradle.kts`

```
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    allprojects {
        apply(from = "repositories.gradle.kts")
    }
}
```